# Azure Machine Learning recommendation

Tags: azure, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to create a recommendation service using Azure ML, more specifically using the Train Matchbox Recommender and Score Matchbox Recommender. Basically, what I want to do is to **recommend the same items** a user has bought in the past, instead of recommending items bought by other people.

[image]

In the picture above, the experiment is configured to recommend items from rated items, then a Evaluate Recommender evaluates the result. In every step I'm saving the data into sqlserver, so that I can check the results myself and see whether it works or not.

[image]

Above we have in the first dataset my purchase history (the userId, the itemId and how many times the user bought that item) and the second is the 5 recommendations. It pretty much nailed the recomendations!

**The problem:** when creating the Predictive Experiment, I must change the Score Matchbox Recommender "Recommended item selection" from "Rated Items (for model evaluation)" to "All items" and deploy the web service.

[image]

After deploying the web service, I ask the recommendations for the user 'FELIPE' and it recommends items that the user has never bought.

Why during the training phase I got the results I expected, and after deploying the service I don't?

[image]

Comment: if you want to recommend based on the user's previous purchase, then there will be less data to train

Comment: @t-prisar The training phase works very well, the recommendations are the same items the user bought previously. Why do I have different results after deploying the service?

Comment: please check the flow

Comment: @t-prisar Would you mind giving the directions? What do you think is wrong?